# Cannot type password in PyPi

Tags: python, module, pypi

I'm trying to publish a module to PyPi and when I run the command `twine upload dist/*` everything works fine, I can type in my name, but then I cannot type anything in the password field, other than clicking enter, I've tried googling it but found none of the solutions worked, there isn't much information on this anyway, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, this might be a really basic answer here (I can't comment on posts yet), but, are you sure you're not just dealing with the fact that by default in most command line interfaces/shells, you won't see any kind of "activity" (not even censored/starred out characters) when typing in a password?

So yeah, you should just try typing out your password and then hitting enter.

It can be a bit annoying when, say, connecting to a server via SSH and you have a lengthy passphrase to type on your private key, but think you might've missed a character (and know which one and where), but because it doesn't display anything, you can't use the arrow keys to go back and position the cursor to the right place to insert it.  You have to just hit backspace an appropriate number of times and start over.

Comment: That worked! Just out of curiosity, why does it do that?